# BSpline combined with explicit and externalcode behaves differently

Tags: openmdao

Below there is a sample code where the BSplineComp is combined either with an ExplicitComp or ExternalCodeComp.
Both of these two do the same calculation and both of the components' gradients are calculated using finite difference.

If I run the version Bspline+ExplicitComp the result is achieved within 2,3 iterations. 
If I run the version Bspline+ExternalCodeComp I have to wait a lot. In this case it is trying to find the gradient of the output with respect to each input. So for example there are 9 control points that are interpolated to 70 points in the bspline component. Then  the external component has to be evaluated as many as the interpolated points (70 times)

So in a case where the bspline is combined with an expensive external code the finite difference requires as much as the number of points it is interpolated to which becomes the bottleneck of the computation.

Based on this input I have two questions

1- If external code component is based on the explicit component what is the major difference that causes the behaviour difference? (considering both have an input of shape=70)

2- In the previously mentioned scneario where the bspline is combined with an expensive external code would there be a more efficient way of combining them apart from the way it is shown here.

MAIN CODE: 'external' variable  is the flag for toggling external/explicit code comp. set that true/false for running the two cases explained above.

```
from openmdao.components.bsplines_comp import BsplinesComp
from openmdao.api import  IndepVarComp, Problem, ExplicitComponent,ExecComp,ExternalCodeComp
from openmdao.api import  ScipyOptimizeDriver, SqliteRecorder, CaseReader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  numpy as np

external=True # change this to true for the case with external code comp. or false for the case with explicit comp.  

rr=np.arange(0,70,1)
"Explicit component for the area under the line calculation" 
class AreaComp(ExplicitComponent):
    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('lenrr', int)        
        self.options.declare('rr', types=np.ndarray)        
    def setup(self):        
        self.add_input('h', shape=lenrr)
        self.add_output('area')
        self.declare_partials(of='area', wrt='h', method='fd')
    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        rr = self.options['rr']        
        outputs['area'] = np.trapz(rr,inputs['h'])          

class ExternalAreaComp(ExternalCodeComp):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('h', shape=70)
        self.add_output('area')

        self.input_file = 'paraboloid_input.dat'
        self.output_file = 'paraboloid_output.dat'

        # providing these is optional; the component will verify that any input
        # files exist before execution and that the output files exist after.
        self.options['external_input_files'] = [self.input_file]
        self.options['external_output_files'] = [self.output_file]

        self.options['command'] = [
            'python', 'extcode_paraboloid.py', self.input_file, self.output_file
        ]

        # this external code does not provide derivatives, use finite difference
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        h = inputs['h']

        # generate the input file for the paraboloid external code
        np.savetxt(self.input_file,h)
        # the parent compute function actually runs the external code
        super(ExternalAreaComp, self).compute(inputs, outputs)

        # parse the output file from the external code and set the value of f_xy
        f_xy=np.load('a.npy')

        outputs['area'] = f_xy


prob  = Problem()
model = prob.model

n_cp = 9
lenrr = len(rr)
"Initialize the design variables"
x = np.random.rand(n_cp)

model.add_subsystem('px', IndepVarComp('x', val=x))
model.add_subsystem('interp', BsplinesComp(num_control_points=n_cp,
                                           num_points=lenrr,
                                           in_name='h_cp',
                                           out_name='h'))

if external:
    comp=ExternalAreaComp()
    model.add_subsystem('AreaComp', comp)
else:
    comp = AreaComp(lenrr=lenrr, rr=rr)
    model.add_subsystem('AreaComp', comp)

case_recorder_filename2 = 'cases4.sql'
recorder2 = SqliteRecorder(case_recorder_filename2)
comp.add_recorder(recorder2)
comp.recording_options['record_outputs']=True
comp.recording_options['record_inputs']=True


model.connect('px.x', 'interp.h_cp')
model.connect('interp.h', 'AreaComp.h')
model.add_constraint('interp.h', lower=0.9, upper=1, indices=[0])

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
#prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'COBYLA'
#prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

model.add_design_var('px.x', lower=1,upper=10)
model.add_objective('AreaComp.area',scaler=1)

prob.setup(check=True)
#prob.run_model()
prob.run_driver()
cr = CaseReader(case_recorder_filename2)

case_keys = cr.system_cases.list_cases()
cou=-1
for case_key in case_keys:
    cou=cou+1
    case = cr.system_cases.get_case(case_key)
    plt.plot(rr,case.inputs['h'],'-*')
```

The external code extcode_paraboloid.py is below

```
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    output_filename = sys.argv[2]

    h=np.loadtxt(input_filename)
    rr=np.arange(0,70,1)

    rk= np.trapz(rr,h)          
    np.save('a',np.array(rk))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases your code takes 3 iterations to run. The wall time for the external code is much much longer simply because of the cost of file-io plus the requirement to make a system call to spool up a new process each time your function is called. 
Yep, system calls are that expensive and file i/o isn't cheap either. If you have a more costly analysis its less of a big deal, but you can see why it should be avoided if at all possible.

In this case you can reduce your FD cost though. Since you have only 9 bspline variables, you have correctly deduced that you could run far fewer FD steps. You want to use the [approximate semi-total derivative](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_totals.html) feature in OpenMDAO v2.4 to set up FD across the group instead of across each individual component.

Its as simple as this:

```
.
. 
. 

if external:
    comp=ExternalAreaComp()
    model.add_subsystem('AreaComp', comp)
else:
    comp = AreaComp(lenrr=lenrr, rr=rr)
    model.add_subsystem('AreaComp', comp)

model.approx_totals()

.
. 
.
```

Comment: thank you very much.the explanation in that part of the manual is also very useful.